# Moving out of state, and car is under parents' names

Tags: united-states, car, car-insurance, moving, georgia

So I'm currently living in New York, but will be relocating to Atlanta next month for a job. I will be taking the car my parents bought me; it is titled under their names, as is the insurance. What I would like to figure out is what I have to do to properly have the car in Atlanta and insured. Do I have to reinsure it in Atlanta under my name? Or can it still be insured under my parents' names?

Comment: How long will you be in Atlanta for the job? If it is only for a few months that is different than making a permanent move.

Comment: It will be for a minimum of a year.

Comment: How you handle the car registration and insurance will be critical to convincing NY state that you are now a resident of Georgia.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to contact your insurance provider to let them know that you are moving and that they need to [transfer your policy](https://www.policygenius.com/blog/7-things-to-do-when-you-move/) to Atlanta from New York. This could either mean a higher or lower premium since different drivers in different states pose different amounts of risk (as well as other factors). However, since the title is under your parents' name, that is [another story](http://blog.esurance.com/out-of-state-car-insurance-everything-you-need-to-know/). They may allow the current insurance policy to stay, or you will need to purchase a new one. You will need to contact your insurance provider for the specific details.

Comment: Alright then im going to get me parent to ask their agent. If i need to get new insurance under my name, would i have to transfer the title over to me name as well?